# How can I show this is equivalent to the error function of $x$?

Tags: special-functions, error-function

$$\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\frac{\sin 2xt}{t}\,dt$$

I know the original $\operatorname{erf}x$ but the infinity in the limit keeps getting in my way. How do I deal with it? Also my hint is that I have to use sine expansion.

Comment: the second term in the integrand looks suspiciously close to the sinc function.

Comment: We haven't done sinc so I don't think I'm allowed to use that! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**  **Using an integral representation of  $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(2xt)}t$**

Let $I(x)$ be given by the integral $I(x)=\frac2\pi\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\frac{\sin(2xt)}{t}\,dt$.  Then, noting that $\frac{\sin(2xt)}t=\int_{-x}^x e^{i2st}\,ds$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
I(x)&=\frac2\pi\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\frac{\sin(2xt)}{t}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\int_{-x}^x e^{i2st}\,ds\,dt\\\\
&=\frac1\pi \int_{-x}^x \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}e^{i2st}\,dt\,ds\\\\
&=\frac1\pi \int_{-x}^x\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s^2}e^{-(t-is)^2}\,dt\,ds\\\\
&=\frac1\pi \int_{-x}^xe^{-s^2}\int_{-\infty-is}^{\infty-is}e^{-t^2}\,dt\,ds\\\\
&=\frac1\pi \int_{-x}^xe^{-s^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt\,ds\\\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\int_0^x e^{-s^2}\,ds\\\\
&=\text{erf}(x)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**  **Using an series representation of  $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(2xt)}t$**

Let $I(x)$ be given by the integral $I(x)=\frac2\pi\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\frac{\sin(2xt)}{t}\,dt$.  Then, noting that $\frac{\sin(2xt)}t=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2xt)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
I(x)&=\frac2\pi\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\frac{\sin(2xt)}{t}\,dt\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\int_0^\infty t^{2n}e^{-t2}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac2\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\left(\frac12\frac{(2n)!}{4^n\,n!}\sqrt{\pi}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)\,n!}\\\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\text{erf}(x)
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Hi! Thanks but I'm completely lost on the 2nd step. Is there another way to do it perhaps using sine expansion? Also please explain the 2nd step and I'll be forever grateful!

Comment: Note that $\frac{\sin(2xt)}{t}=\int_{-x}^x e^{i2st}\,ds$.  Also, note that the integrand of the original integral expression is even in $t$.  So, we can exploit that symmetry and integrate over $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and then divide by $2$.

Comment: Is there a name for this identity? How does it work?

Comment: It's just simple integration.  The antiderivative of $e^{i2st}$ is $\frac{e^{i2st}}{i2t}$ and $$\frac{e^{i2xt}-e^{-i2xt}}{i2t}=\frac{\sin(2xt)}{t}$$

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense. Had to look up the sine complex identity but it fits together. It's just for the purpose of this course I'd like to narrow my thinking down to only special functions and power series expansions.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, expand $\sin(2xt)$ in its Maclaurin series and integrate term-by-term.  To justify the interchange of limits, you can estimate the error in the Maclaurin series, or you can use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, noting that $\int_0^\infty \exp(-t^2 + 2|x|t)\; dt$ converges.